# How to join array values in jQuery but formatting them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, join

I have the following input in Javascript: `["1213381233", "1213551233", "1213551255"]` and I need to join them and format them. Take a look to the following example:

```
<div id="segment_form">
  <button id="add_condition">
    Click me
  </button>
</div>
```

```js
var data_field = 'asset_locations_name';
var data_condition = 'in';
var data_values = ["1213381233", "1213551233", "1213551255"];

$("#segment_form").on('click', '#add_condition', function() {
  var li = '';
  var has_parenthesis = false;

  if (data_condition == 'in' || data_condition == 'not in' || data_condition == 'between' || data_condition == 'not between') {
    has_parenthesis = true;
  }

  if (data_values instanceof Array && data_values.length >= 1) {
    li += '<li data-field="' + data_field + '" data-condition="' + data_condition + '">';
    li += data_field + ' ' + data_condition;

    if (has_parenthesis) {
      li += '( ';
    }

    $.each(data_values, function(index, value) {
      li += '<span title="Click to remove this item from the list" data-id="' + value + '">' + value + '</span>';
    });

    if (has_parenthesis) {
      li += ' )';
    }
    li += '</li>';
  }

  $('body').append(li);
});
```

The idea is to have the following output:

`asset_locations_name in (1213381233,1213551233,1213551255)`

My code is almost working but I am getting:

`asset_locations_name in( 121338123312135512331213551255 )`

The trick here is I can't do a `data_values.join()` because I need the value of each to add as a `data-id` property on the span itself.

Any other clean solution? Any help is welcome!

I forgot to mention there is a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/v562vst9/) ready to play with.

Comment: Add `+ ","` to the end your your `li += <span` then remove with `substring`, `substr`, or `replace(/,$/, "")`

Comment: You should also do `$('body').append($('<ul>').append(li));` instead of just `$('body').append(li);`, which is invalid html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
var data_field = 'asset_locations_name';
var data_condition = 'in';
var data_values = ["1213381233", "1213551233", "1213551255"];

$("#segment_form").on('click', '#add_condition', function() {
  var li = '';
  var has_parenthesis = false;

  if (data_condition == 'in' || data_condition == 'not in' || data_condition == 'between' || data_condition == 'not between') {
    has_parenthesis = true;
  }

  if (data_values instanceof Array && data_values.length >= 1) {
    li += '<li data-field="' + data_field + '" data-condition="' + data_condition + '">';
    li += data_field + ' ' + data_condition;

    if (has_parenthesis) {
      li += '(';
    }

    $.each(data_values, function(index, value) {
      // Note the 'prefix' variable here
      var prefix = (index == 0) ? '' : ', ';
      li += '<span title="Click to remove this item from the list" data-id="' + value + '">' + prefix + value + '</span>';
    });

    if (has_parenthesis) {
      li += ')';
    }
    li += '</li>';
  }

  console.log('data_field =>', data_field, 'data_condition => ', data_condition, 'data_values =>', data_values, 'li =>', li);

  $('body').append(li);
});
```

I created a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/293o53ta/) with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just add ',' after all your value and get the substring without the last ','.

https://jsfiddle.net/v562vst9/2/

```
<div id="segment_form">
  <button id="add_condition">
    Click me
  </button>
</div>
```

```js
var data_field = 'asset_locations_name';
var data_condition = 'in';
var data_values = ["1213381233", "1213551233", "1213551255"];

$("#segment_form").on('click', '#add_condition', function() {
  var li = '';
  var has_parenthesis = false;

  if (data_condition == 'in' || data_condition == 'not in' || data_condition == 'between' || data_condition == 'not between') {
    has_parenthesis = true;
  }

  if (data_values instanceof Array && data_values.length >= 1) {
    li += '<li data-field="' + data_field + '" data-condition="' + data_condition + '">';
    li += data_field + ' ' + data_condition;

    if (has_parenthesis) {
      li += '( ';
    }

    $.each(data_values, function(index, value) {
      li += '<span title="Click to remove this item from the list" data-id="' + value + '">' + value + '</span>,';
    });

    li = li.substr(0, li.length - 1);

    if (has_parenthesis) {
      li += ' )';
    }
    li += '</li>';
  }

  console.log('data_field =>', data_field, 'data_condition => ', data_condition, 'data_values =>', data_values, 'li =>', li);

  $('body').append(li);
});
```

Comment: The `$('body').append(li);` is incorrect, since `li` should have either an `ol` or an `ul` parent. It should be `$('body').append($('<ul>').append(li));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma if it's not the last element.
Maybe something like this:

```
$.each(data_values, function(index, value) {
  li += '<span title="Click to remove this item from the list" data-id="' + value + '">' + value + '</span>';
  if (index !== data_values.length - 1) {
    li += ','
  }
});
```

Or remove the last comma after iterate.

```
$.each(data_values, function(index, value) {
  li += '<span title="Click to remove this item from the list" data-id="' + value + '">' + value + '</span>';
});
li.slice(0,-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the js method 'join'

You should have a look to something like handlebars

```js
var data_values = ["1213381233", "1213551233", "1213551255"];

alert(data_values.join(','))
```