# How to remove the "," on item deletion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
<ul class="ul" id="selected_conditions">
  <li data-field="asset_locations_name" data-condition="in">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete_condition" aria-hidden="true" title="Click to remove this condition from the list"></i> WHERE asset_locations_name IN(
    <span class="condition_item" data-id="1213381233">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete" title="Click to remove this item from the list" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1213381233
    </span>,
    <span class="condition_item" data-id="1212371897">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete" title="Click to remove this item from the list" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1212371897
    </span> )
  </li>
</ul>
```

Each time I click on the little icon `.delete` I should remove the current value and I was able to achieve that with the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#selected_conditions').on('click', '.delete', function(ev) {
    var item_id = $(this).parent().data('id');
    $('.condition_item[data-id="'+ item_id +'"]').remove();
  });
});
```

But the code above has two problems: if I remove any item the symbol `,` isn't removed and that's wrong as an a second one I can't have an emtpy `()` string, so:

- How do I remove the `,` so I not end up with a bad string like `(,1213381233)` or `(1213381233,)`?

Any help? I have leave you a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/8184ok2e/1/) to play with. This is a WIP so if you have a suggestion or better solution feel free to add it to your answer.

Comment: Don't use a list. Use an array and `.join(',')` it into a string only when you need one.

Comment: @Blazemonger check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529833/how-to-join-array-values-in-jquery-but-formatting-them) that would tell you why I didn't use `.join()`

Comment: @CBroe can you provide an idea? it would be fine to have an example of what you're thinking about

Comment: Blazemonger already described that in more detail in their answer. As for the counting of elements, all you need to do is check the length property of the jQuery selection: `$('#selected_conditions .condition_item').length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the comma(s), I'd use CSS `:before` to add commas only when there's more than one item in a row.

```
.condition_item+.condition_item:before {
  content: ", "
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8184ok2e/2/

Comment: Perfect, that works and answer my first question, do you have an idea or solution for the second one so I can fully accept your answer?

Comment: @ReynierPM In SO you should ask one question per post - so you should accept this answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: You shouldn't ask more than one question per post anyway. But, you can easily count the `span`s with something like [`$('#selected_conditions .condition_item').length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) -- https://jsfiddle.net/8184ok2e/5/

Comment: @gus27 I've edited the question and changing all to be just one, I will move the other doubt to another post, could you remove the downvote?

Comment: @ReynierPM I didn't downvote this question. Thanks for splitting the post.

Comment: @Blazemonger can you move your comment as an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550810/how-to-count-the-elements-on-deletion-so-i-not-end-up-with-an-empty) ??